# how to improve apache flume performance to write data in hbase

Tags: flume

I m using apache-flume1.4.0 with hbase0.94.10 and hadoop1.1.2.
flume agent have spool directory as source and hbase as sink and file channel.It is running successfully but very slow.what should I do for improving hbase write performance.

Flume agent conf is as below:

```
agent1.sources = spool
agent1.channels = fileChannel
agent1.sinks = sink

agent1.sources.spool.type = spooldir
agent1.sources.spool.spoolDir = /opt/spoolTest/
agent1.sources.spool.fileSuffix = .completed
agent1.sources.spool.channels = fileChannel
#agent1.sources.spool.deletePolicy = immediate

agent1.sinks.sink.type = org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.HBaseSink
agent1.sinks.sink.channel = fileChannel
agent1.sinks.sink.table = test
agent1.sinks.sink.columnFamily = log
agent1.sinks.sink.serializer = org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.RegexHbaseEventSerializer
agent1.sinks.sink.serializer.regex = (.*)^C(.*)^C(.*)^C(.*)^C(.*)^C(.*)^C(.*)^C(.*)^C(.*)^C(.*)^C(.*)^C(.*)^C(.*)^C(.*)
agent1.sinks.sink.serializer.colNames = id,no_fill_reason,adInfo,locationInfo,handsetInfo,siteInfo,reportDate,ipaddress,headerContent,userParaContent,reqParaContent,otherPara,others,others1
agent1.sinks.sink1.batchSize = 100

agent1.channels.fileChannel.type = file
agent1.channels.fileChannel.checkpointDir = /usr/flumeFileChannel/chkpointFlume
agent1.channels.fileChannel.dataDirs = /usr/flumeFileChannel/dataFlume
agent1.channels.fileChannel.capacity = 10000000
agent1.channels.fileChannel.transactionCapacity = 100000
```

What should be capacity,transaction capacity of file channel and batch size of sink.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share your spool-directories file ? Were u able to load data into multiple columns from your above code ?